# does continued use of segues keep adding to the stack

Tags: ios, segue

if a navigation controller not used (don't want a back function), and segues between two view controllers are connected directly via buttons, does this cause the stack to continue growing every time you switch from one view controller to the other?  Does this cause problems?  This is the first time I am using segues without the navigation controller to unstack things with the <

Comment: Yes, if you keep segueing "forward" then you will presenting an ever-deepening stack of view controllers modally on top of each other.  I suggest that you use an outer container view controller and have the buttons switch the contained view controller instance between your two options, much like a tab bar view controller does

Comment: Thank you!!  I was afraid of that.   I saw some other stuff on using the unwind function in the second view controller to go back to the first...will this prevent the stack from building up?  I tried the tab bar view controller too, but want to use a switch instead....  if that unwind thing doesn't prevent the stack build, I'll try to figure out a way to use an outer container...  sounds more difficult though, and I'm pretty much a newbie...

Comment: You can use segue from VC1->VC2 and unwind from VC2->VC1, this will give you the same VC1 but a new VC2 each time.  Using a container will let you switch between a single VC1 and a single VC2 so each view controller will keep its current state; it depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: OK, thanks again.  I'll try the unwind to see if the result is OK... I want to retain information in V2 also (using Userdefaults to save switch positions, etc...).  Using a container sounds like it probably would be a better idea... I liked the tab bar controller's way of switching between the two, but I just don't want the tab bar....  If I use a container to connect the two VCs, would it just be an NSObject or another VC as the container with say, a switch with an IBAction to determine which segue to go to?  How would I make it invisible as the first VC like the tab controller is?

Comment: Answering my own inquiry with this excellent site if anyone else wants to know how to create a container view controller.  https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/